How to setup Google OAuth into AWS Amplify Authenticator?
I have setup AWS Authenticator and got it to work as shown in the code below. This setup is working for our frontend built in React.
const awsconfig = {
  Auth: {
    Cognito: {
      userPoolClientId: import.meta.env.VITE_COGNITO_POOL_CLIENT_ID,
      userPoolId: import.meta.env.VITE_USER_POOL_ID,
    },
  },
};

Amplify.configure(awsconfig);
<Authenticator loginMechanisms={['email']}>
  // Code for the app
</Authenticator>

I would now like to add Google OAuth to this and have consulted the official documentation to do so (https://docs.amplify.aws/gen1/javascript/build-a-backend/auth/add-social-provider/). So far my setup is as follows:
// Define oauthConfig with required properties
const oauthConfig = {
  domain: 'https://demo-amplify-app.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com',
  scopes: ['email', 'profile', 'openid'],
  responseType: 'code',
  redirectSignIn: [
    'http://localhost:3000/',
  ],
  redirectSignOut: [
    'http://localhost:3000/',
  ],
};

// Define userPoolConfig with user pool details
const userPoolConfig = {
  userPoolClientId: import.meta.env.VITE_COGNITO_POOL_CLIENT_ID || '',
  userPoolId: import.meta.env.VITE_USER_POOL_ID || '',
};

// Construct the awsconfig object with correct structure
const awsconfig = {
  Auth: {
    Cognito: {
      ...userPoolConfig,
      loginWith: {
        oauth: oauthConfig,
      },
    },
  },
};

Amplify.configure(awsconfig);
    <Authenticator loginMechanisms={['email']} socialProviders={['google']}>
      // Code for the app
    </Authenticator>

This seems to be the exact setup that the official docs state however I'm running into the error:
Argument of type '{ Auth: { Cognito: { loginWith: { oauth: { domain: string; scopes: string[]; responseType: string; redirectSignIn: string[]; redirectSignOut: string[]; }; }; userPoolClientId: any; userPoolId: any; }; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ResourcesConfig | LegacyConfig | AmplifyOutputs'.
  Type '{ Auth: { Cognito: { loginWith: { oauth: { domain: string; scopes: string[]; responseType: string; redirectSignIn: string[]; redirectSignOut: string[]; }; }; userPoolClientId: any; userPoolId: any; }; }; }' is not assignable to type 'ResourcesConfig'.
    Types of property 'Auth' are incompatible.
      Type '{ Cognito: { loginWith: { oauth: { domain: string; scopes: string[]; responseType: string; redirectSignIn: string[]; redirectSignOut: string[]; }; }; userPoolClientId: any; userPoolId: any; }; }' is not assignable to type 'AuthConfig | undefined'.
        Type '{ Cognito: { loginWith: { oauth: { domain: string; scopes: string[]; responseType: string; redirectSignIn: string[]; redirectSignOut: string[]; }; }; userPoolClientId: any; userPoolId: any; }; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<AuthUserPoolAndIdentityPoolConfig & Partial<Record<never, never>>> & Pick<AuthUserPoolAndIdentityPoolConfig & Partial<...>, "Cognito">'. Type '{ Cognito: { loginWith: { oauth: { domain: string; scopes: string[]; responseType: string; redirectSignIn: string[]; redirectSignOut: string[]; }; }; userPoolClientId: any; userPoolId: any; }; }' is not assignable to type 'Partial<AuthUserPoolAndIdentityPoolConfig & Partial<Record<never, never>>>'.
            Types of property 'Cognito' are incompatible.
              Type '{ loginWith: { oauth: { domain: string; scopes: string[]; responseType: string; redirectSignIn: string[]; redirectSignOut: string[]; }; }; userPoolClientId: any; userPoolId: any; }' is not assignable to type 'CognitoUserPoolAndIdentityPoolConfig'.
                Type '{ loginWith: { oauth: { domain: string; scopes: string[]; responseType: string; redirectSignIn: string[]; redirectSignOut: string[]; }; }; userPoolClientId: any; userPoolId: any; }' is not assignable to type 'CognitoUserPoolConfig'.
                  The types of 'loginWith.oauth.responseType' are incompatible between these types.
                    Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"code" | "token"'.ts(2345)

I'm unsure how I can resolve this error. It seems according to the docs I'm using the correct type but perhaps I'm missing something. I've tried some other attempts and similarly get type errors when I try to run it. With that said, any assistance on this would be extremely appreciated! I'm not sure what the correct type should be to allow for the Google OAuth.

were you able to make this work? I'm trying to make Amplify Authenticator to work with Cognito Hosted UI.

This is how I did with Auth0:
import { signInWithRedirect } from 'aws-amplify/auth';
import { Label, View, withAuthenticator } from "@aws-amplify/ui-react";

const appConfig = getAppConfig() // custom function to load properties

const provider = {
  custom: 'auth0IdP'
}

function handleSignInClick() {
  signInWithRedirect({ provider })
}

Amplify.configure({
  Auth: {
    Cognito: {
      userPoolId: appConfig.CognitoUserPoolId,
      userPoolClientId: appConfig.CognitoUserPoolClientId,
      identityPoolId: appConfig.CognitoIdentityPoolId,
      loginWith: {
        oauth: {
          domain: "yourcognitdomain.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com",
          scopes: ["email", "openid", "profile"],
          redirectSignIn: ["http://localhost:3000"],
          redirectSignOut: ["http://localhost:3000"],
          responseType: 'code',
          providers: [{custom: "auth0IdP"}],
        }
      },
    },
  },
  API: {
    REST: {
      "backend": {
        endpoint: appConfig.BackendApiUrl,
        region: appConfig.BackendApiRegion,
      }
    }
  }
});

const components = {
  SignIn: {
    Header() {
      return (
        <View textAlign="center">
          <Divider></Divider>
          <Label>Federated Login</Label>
          <br></br>
          <Button
            onClick={() => {
              handleSignInClick()
            }}
            className="amplify-button amplify-field-group__control amplify-button--primary amplify-button--fullwidth"
            style={{ width: "87%" }}
            size="small"
          >
            Sign In with Auth0
          </Button>
          <Divider></Divider>
          <Label>Cognito Login</Label>
        </View>
      );
    },
    FormFields: null
  },
}

handleSignInEvents()

const App: React.FC = () => {

  return (
    <ConfigProvider
      theme={{
        token: {
          // Seed Token
          colorPrimary: '#6a207f',

        },
      }}>
      <Routes>
        <Route
          path="/"
          element={<Navigate to={"/main"} />} />
        <Route
          path="/main"
          element={<Main />} />
      </Routes>
    </ConfigProvider>
  );
};

export default withAuthenticator(App, { hideSignUp: true, components: components })

Your CognitoUserPoolId needs to be the id of your Cognito User pool. This cognito user pool also needs to have an App Integration with a Hosted UI that accepts Identity providers, in my case was Cognito User pool and Auth0, because I need to accept users from Cognito User pool and users from Auth0. The Auth0 provider needs to be configured with the same name as in the code that I've shared, in my case I named it "auth0IdP". Notice that I've implemented a custom button in the Amplify authenticator named "Sign In with Auth0", which invokes handleSignInClick(), which calls signInWithRedirect. signInWithRedirect is an Amplify hook, you can listen to events from the Auth Hub, you can take a look here https://docs.amplify.aws/react/build-a-backend/auth/connect-your-frontend/listen-to-auth-events/#listen-to-and-log-auth-events
Also refer to this post: https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/auth0-saml-cognito-user-pool. This is the first post I started with, and took me days until I got it working.
